# Issue with Snowflake JDBC Driver 3.13.20 - Timezone Changes and Date Formatting

Tags: timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I recently upgraded my Snowflake JDBC driver from version 3.13.19 to 3.13.20 and encountered some unexpected issues related to timezones and date formatting. I'm reaching out to the community for assistance as I couldn't find any information about these changes in the release notes or official documentation.

After upgrading to version 3.13.20, I noticed that the date values retrieved from the result set using the getDate() method are now returning values with an 8 or 7-hour difference. This difference seems to be related to timezone changes. Previously, the date values were aligned with the timezone of the JVM, but now they seem to be in a different timezone.

To make matters more challenging, Snowflake now expects a different date-time format, which has caused compatibility issues with my existing code. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any explicit information about these timezone changes or the required date-time format in the release notes or documentation for version 3.13.20.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or experiences from anyone else who has encountered similar problems with the Snowflake JDBC driver, specifically after upgrading to version 3.13.20. Have you experienced discrepancies in the date values, changes in the expected date-time format, or noticed any impacts related to the updated TZDB version? If so, have you found any workarounds or solutions to address these issues?

Additionally, if anyone has come across any information regarding the timezone changes, the updated TZDB version, and the required date-time format in the Snowflake JDBC driver version 3.13.20, please share it with the community. I have scoured the release notes and documentation but couldn't find any relevant details.

Thank you all in advance for your valuable assistance and insights. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Additionally, I discovered that Snowflake has updated the timezone database (TZDB) version used. This leads me to wonder if the changes in the TZDB version could be causing the discrepancies in the date values and the unexpected timezone differences I'm experiencing. However, I couldn't find any explicit information about these timezone changes or their impact in the release notes or documentation for version 3.13.20.

EDIT:
I also tried to update the driver from 3.12.17 to 3.13.32. Later on I found out that the error occured in version 3.13.20. That's why I am mentioning this version and trying to find any info in release notes/documentation about the changes here.

Here is the example, how the data changed between versions. There is also listed the format of these dates.

```
Date = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm Z
TimeNoMS = HH:mm:ss.SSS Z
TimeMS = HH:mm:ss.SSS Z
TimestampNTZ_NoMS = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
TimestampNTZ_MS = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
TimestampTZ_NoMS = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z
TimestampTZ_MS = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z
TimestampLTZ_NoMS = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z
TimestampLTZ_MS = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z

           Date                      |TimeNoMS           |TimeMS                    |TimestampNTZ_NoMS          |TimestampNTZ_MS           |TimestampTZ_NoMS                |TimestampTZ_MS                 |TimestampLTZ_NoMS              |TimestampLTZ_MS               |

3.12.17    #2021-01-16 00:00 +0000   22:46:42.000 +0000   22:46:42.123 +0000        2021-01-16 13:46:42.000     2021-01-16 13:46:42.123     2021-01-16 22:46:42.000 +0000   2021-01-16 22:46:42.123 +0000   2021-01-16 22:46:42.000 +0000   2021-01-16 22:46:42.123 +0000

3.13.32    #2021-01-16 01:00 +0100   22:46:42.000 +0100   22:46:42.123 +0100        2021-01-16 14:46:42.000     2021-01-16 14:46:42.123     2021-01-16 15:46:42.000 +0100   2021-01-16 15:46:42.000 +0100   2021-01-16 23:46:42.000 +0100   2021-01-16 23:46:42.123 +0100
```

As you can see, in version 3.13.32 it started to put +0100. Also in some cases there is +1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can control this behavior on user or session level.

See the [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user);

E.g. To change the timezone:

```
ALTER USER <username> set TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

Same applies to to the Output format:

```
ALTER USER  <username> set TIMESTAMP_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'
```

Date/time output format [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output)

Alternatively changing it to the user you can choose explicitly setting this details only for the current JDBC connection. See another [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/jdbc/jdbc-configure#connection-parameters) with examples.

Also `3.13.20` is not a very recent version. I suggest considering upgrade to something like `3.13.31`

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment, I edited my post, can u please review it again and give me a hint? Thanks

Comment: Hi, no problem. What is your actual issue now?

Comment: Can you please look here, and try to help me?
https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D7Do000000qOGvKAM/detail